# Arduino web socket autoreconnect

Tags: websocket, arduino, esp8266

I am using 2 esp8266, both connected to same network. Esp1 send some data to esp2 using websocket. So basically esp2 connect to esp1 websocket and read data.
My problem is that if esp1 is restarted, after is up again, esp2 does not connect anymore to it and needs restart to connect 
This is code I am using on esp2

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WebSocketsClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define USE_SERIAL Serial
#define LEDS 0 //Status led

WebSocketsClient webSocket;
SoftwareSerial COM(5, 4); 

long previousMillis = 0;
long interval = 50;

String data;

void webSocketEvent(WStype_t type, uint8_t * payload, size_t length) {
    switch(type) {
        case WStype_DISCONNECTED:
            yield();
            break;
        case WStype_CONNECTED: {
            webSocket.sendTXT("Connected");
        }
   yield();
            break;
        case WStype_TEXT:
      if(payload[0] == '#') {
        uint32_t dataz = (uint32_t) strtol((const char *) &payload[1], NULL, 10);
        if (dataz < 99911) {
          data = "0" + String(dataz);
        }
        else {
          data = String(dataz);
        }
      }
      yield();
if (data.length() == 6 ) {
COM.print('<'); // start marker
COM.print(data);
COM.println('>'); // end marker
}
       break;
    }

}

void setup() {
  pinMode(LEDS, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LEDS, LOW);
    for(uint8_t t = 4; t > 0; t--) {
        delay(1000);
    }

 WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
 WiFi.begin("xxx", "xxx");
 while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    delay(500);
  }
    // server address, port and URL
    webSocket.begin("192.168.0.30", 81, "/");

    // event handler
    webSocket.onEvent(webSocketEvent);

    // use HTTP Basic Authorization this is optional remove if not needed
    //webSocket.setAuthorization("user", "Password");

    // try ever 5000 again if connection has failed
    webSocket.setReconnectInterval(5000);
  digitalWrite(LEDS, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  if(currentMillis - previousMillis > interval) {
        previousMillis = currentMillis;

    webSocket.loop();
  }
}
```

I would need some help to make it reconnect when the esp1 is available again after was disconnected
Thank you very much

Comment: why do you use websockets in local network between two esp? use UDP or TCP sockets (WiFiServer and WiFiClient)

Comment: you need to do something in the `WStype_DISCONNECTED`; reset, wait and try to connect, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

webSocket.loop(); should be outside of if statement.

Comment: Will change it and will let you know. Thanks